# loss function in LSTM neural network

Tags: deep-learning, keras, lstm

I do not understand what is being minimized in these networks.
Can someone please explain what is going on mathematically when the loss gets smaller in LSTM network?

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [keras documentation](https://keras.io/objectives/), `categorical_crossentropy` is just the multiclass logloss. Math and theoretical explanation for log loss [here](http://www.exegetic.biz/blog/2015/12/making-sense-logarithmic-loss/).

Basically, the LSTM is assigning labels to words (or characters, depending on your model), and optimizing the model by penalizing incorrect labels in word (or character) sequences. The model takes an input word or character vector, and tries to guess the next "best" word, based on training examples. Categorical crossentropy is a quantitative way of measuring how good the guess is. As the model iterates over the training set, it makes less mistakes in guessing the next best word (or character).

Comment: good info. I wonder what is so wrong with the question that it got -4

Comment: Maybe it's better suited for Cross Validated or the Data Science or Computer Science stacks, but since you're asking about a specific implementation in keras, I think that's arguable.